# Use Parent Position but not rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

is there a way to make a GameObject use parent position but world rotation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, at least if you are thinking of magical checkbox or other ready solution. You would need to remove object from parent and add code, that move the object each time the parent moves.

Comment: made a simple sulotion that "works" with heavy quotes lol 

`void Update()
{
transform.position = _parent.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 1.5f);
}`
now I wanna know if there's a simple trigger function for when the Parent Object moves rather than using `Update`

Comment: That's actually what I thought, at least for physics based movement. If you just change the position of the parent, you could implement a method, that moves the so-called child as well. You can make an event, so more child could subscribe, or just reference and move all "children" in this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate you rotation and translation into few objects, changing your hierarchy like so:

```
Moving Cube
- Parent Cube
- Child Cube
```

now, moving `Moving Cube` will move both `Parent Cube` and `Child Cube` and rotating `Parent Cube` won't affect `Child Cube`